# Are there examples of sequences $(x_n)$ such that $(x_n) \in l^p(\mathbb{N})$ but $(x_n) \not\in l^p(\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I'm curious about whether/how a bi-directional sequence can have stricter conditions for convergence than a sequence over $\mathbb{N}$. I assume that this is possible, but haven't been able to generate any examples on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. A bijection $\varphi:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ induces an isomorphism $\ell^p(\mathbb{N}) \to \ell^p(\mathbb{Z})$ given by $(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mapsto (y_j = x_{\varphi^{-1}(j)})_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}$, sending each entry at position $i$  to become the entry at position $\varphi(i)$. You may check that this is an isometry by writing the definition of the measure in each side, and noting that we may always rearrange sums of positive numbers.

There is some ambiguity in the question, and maybe you meant a restriction to half a sequence instead, in the following sense: If you take the sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ with $x_n = 0$ whenever $n \geq 0$ and $x_n = 1$ whenever $n < 0$, then the restricted sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is in $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$ while the full sequence is not in $\ell^p(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Yes, I had the same question as you phrase in your 2nd paragraph.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I assumed because the same operator can behave very differently on the two spaces, that there would be a difference in the types of sequences in the space.

Comment: I see @avs, then you should note that this construction works in a more general way. Take any sequence $(x_n)$ in $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$, and any sequence at all, maybe a sequence $(y_n)$ not in $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$. Then define $(z_k)$, with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, as $z_k = x_k$ whenever $n \geq 0$ and $z_k = y_{- k - 1}$ whenever $k < 0$. You can check that $(z_k) \in \ell^p(\mathbb{Z})$ iff $(y_n) \in \ell^p(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: Thanks, @jacobian but my main doubt is whether the OP intended this particular (symmetric) extension of a sequence from $l^{p}({\mathbb N})$ to one in $l^{p}({\mathbb Z})$.